# MarkLogic: Optics API unstable time taken/runtime

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-optic-api

I have been playing around with MarkLogic Optics API Capabilities and noticed that the time taken to complete my code execution is unstable, where it can take up to 40 seconds or ~1-2 minutes to complete, there are also times it will also takes more then an hours which will activate a timeout error.

Is this due to caches or a certain settings that I might be missing out? Or is the low runtime due to caches from previous failed/incomplete executions? I have posted one set of my codes below as it might help in this troubleshooting.

```
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
import module namespace ofn="http://marklogic.com/optic/expression/fn" at "/MarkLogic/optic/optic-fn.xqy";
import module namespace thsr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/thesaurus" 
   at "/MarkLogic/thesaurus.xqy";

xdmp:set-transaction-time-limit(3600),
let $people := op:from-lexicons(
  map:entry("comments",cts:uri-reference()),
  "lexicon")
  =>op:where(
   thsr:expand(
   cts:element-word-query(xs:QName("text"),"go"), 
   thsr:lookup("/myThsrDocs/wordnet.xml", "go"),
   (), 
   (), 
   () )
  )

let $questions := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?comment </date_commented> ?date. }', "sparql")
                => op:select(( "date", op:as('commentStr',ofn:string(op:col('comment'))) ))

return(
xdmp:elapsed-time(),
$questions  => op:join-inner(
    $people,
    op:on(
      "comments","commentStr"
    )
  )
  => op:select(("comments")) 
  => op:group-by((), op:count("Total","comments"))
  => op:result()
,
xdmp:elapsed-time()
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably due to different query plans being picked, and indicates a possible bug in the cost function. You should work with MarkLogic support to track down the problem and open a bug for it.

Comment: A footnote on the good advice above:  try inserting `=> op:prepare(2)` immediately before the op:result() call to see whether dedicating a little more time to optimizing the plan reduces the variability in the time.  See http://docs.marklogic.com/op:prepare

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it doesn't seem to help. Instead it also results in the following error `[1.0-ml] SVC-EXTIME:plan:execute(plan:sparql(...),(),()) -- Time limit exceeded`. After doing some runs I noticed that a timeout occurs when the node which I'm running the query on does not seem to be processing anything after running for a certain amount of time. It will usually start at 100% CPU and suddenly drop to ~0.3%-15% CPU usage @ehennum

Comment: It also seems to complete quickly when all my nodes are running at a 100% CPU Usage. Is there a certain option I can choose to force MarkLogic into using all my resources?

Comment: Given that using prepare() to optimize the plan didn't work, the best approach is the one in the answer:  submit the issue to MarkLogic support to enlist others in the investigation.